# SMPlayer does not disable screensaver

Tags: linux-mint, screensaver, mplayer

I am running SMPlayer 0.8.0 (mplayer frontend) on Linux Mint 14 64bit, when I play a movie and stop using the peripherals the screensaver kicks in after a while.
I have checked the "Disable screensaver" option in the preferences, but it does not do that. Neither does running mplayer from the terminal. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm currently trying out a different solution and keeping gnome-screensaver: open smplayer, menu options > preferences > advanced (left menu) and select "Options for SMPlayer". There try adding this: `-heartbeat-cmd "gnome-screensaver-command -d"` -- then restart the smplayer. Not sure if it works, that's why this is a comment for now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/428884) having to do with the way that gnome3 controls the screensaver. Haven't looked into it for a while now but I used to have the same thing with vlc. According to the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XScreenSaver#MPlayer), you have two options. You can either disable it for `mplayer` (which should also work for `smplayer`) specifically, or you could use another program disable it for various programs.

### The mplayer way

First, replace `gnome-screensaver` with `xscreensaver`:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-screensaver 
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

Then, add the following to `~/.mplayer/config`:

```
heartbeat-cmd="xscreensaver-command -deactivate >&- 2>&- &"
```

### lightsOn

LighstOn is a simple BASH script that will inhibit the screensaver when it detects any of a list of user defined programs (mplayer, and therefore smplayer, are on the list by default) running **in full screen mode**.

Replace `gnome-screensaver` with `xscreensaver`: as described above. Then, download lightsOn from [here](https://github.com/iye/lightsOn/blob/master/lightsOn.sh). I just tried it and it works perfectly. You might want to make it start automatically by adding it to Cinnamon's start up application list.

### caffeine

Caffeine is a system tray applet for Gnome3 (it may or may not work in Cinnamon, I have not tried it). According to [this site](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/2-ways-to-temporarily-disable.html), you can give it a list of programs and it will inhibit the screensaver if they are running (full screen or not). According to the same site, it can work with both `xscreensaver` and `gnome-screensaver` so you may want to check it out.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine python-glade2
```

Comment: I will try that, but I have to add that VLC does not have this issue. 

PS. Is cinnamon DE based on gnome3?

Comment: @b-vigilanT  VLC does not have it? Hmm, OK cause I just tested it on vlc and it worked :). Not surprising if the problem was not there. I will check smplayer next. Yes, cinnamon is a fork of GNOME3.

Comment: @b-vigilanT I found a better solution, see my updated answer.

Comment: Actually, your first solution worked out fine. I watched whole of Harry Potter three, lying in my bed and subsequently falling asleep in it. :) 

But it's nice to know about those programs. :)

Comment: 14.04 ubuntu, smplayer: lightsOn.sh did work! but caffeine did not..